# Understanding python 2.7 email.feedparser Feedparser __init__ function

Tags: python, python-2.7

*(So I'm trying to learn python. I figured it would be good to read code by people better than me. I decided to read through the email module...)*

The `init` function for the Feedparser class in the `email.feedparser` module is defined as:

```
def __init__(self, _factory=message.Message):
    """_factory is called with no arguments to create a new message obj"""
    self._factory = _factory
    self._input = BufferedSubFile()
    self._msgstack = []
    self._parse = self._parsegen().next
    self._cur = None
    self._last = None
    self._headersonly = False
```

The line I'm having trouble with is:

```
self._parse = self._parsegen().next
```

Which I think should mean 'set the attribute `self._parse` to the value of the `next` attribute of the return value of the method `self._parsegen()`

As far as I can tell, `self._parsgen()` when called during `__init__()` will first call `self._new_message()` which will set/add values to `self._cur`, `self._last`, and `self._msgstack`. It will then assign an empty list object to the local variable `headers` then start iterating over the `self._input` object. I think the first value for `line` will be a `NeedMoreData` object. Since the `NeedMoreData` class just extends object it should have no attribute or method named `next`. So does `next` just refer back to the iterator (`self._input`)?

Is there any way to have a look at this in the interpreter so that I can step through each line of the script?

Comment: You can set a debugger breakpoint in any code (your own, 3rd party modules or the Python parts of the standard library) like this:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

That will kick you into the built in debugger, pdb, as soon as that line of code is hit. You can then use `n` to execute the next line (step over), `s` to step into the evaluation of the next line (a function call for example), `w` to show the call stack, `l` to display some code context around the line you're at, and of course do whatever you can do in the regular interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So does `next` just refer back to the iterator (`self._input`)?

`next` does refer to the *generator*. Since the `_parsegen()` method uses `yield`, it returns a generator object. Consider the following simple example (from IPython):

```
In [1]: def a():
   ...:     yield 1
   ...:     yield 2
   ...:     

In [2]: a()
Out[2]: <generator object a at 0x1a56550>

In [3]: a().next
Out[3]: <method-wrapper 'next' of generator object at 0x1a567d0>

In [4]: a().next()
Out[4]: 1
```

So, yes, you are mostly right. It will fall down to the iterator, and reference the method returning the next value from it.

> Is there any way to have a look at this in the interpreter so that I can step through each line of the script?

You can use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `next` method is a way to generate the next value of a python `iterator` or `generator`. The easiest way to think about this is to rewrite a for-loop.

You have a really easy syntax for looping over a list:

```
for element in list:
    print element
```

which will produce an `element` on each iteration.  But under the hood, Python is actually doing something akin to this:

```
iterator = iter(list)
while True:
    element = iterator.next()
    # do something with element (e.g. print it)
    print element
```

When the iterator is exhausted (has no more items), it raises the `StopIteration` exception, which is how `for` loops and other methods employing iterators know when to stop. (so the previous code snippet should really be wrapped in a `try/except` block, but I figured it would be clearer to read without it).

You can read about the [protocol for iterators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) in the Python docs. (but basically anything can be an iterator if it defines `__iter__` and produces an iterator that defines `__iter__` and  `next`.